# Border radius not working in samsung galaxy j7

Tags: android, css, angular, hybrid-mobile-app, samsung-galaxy

I have an angular app which contain code

```
<div class="round">
  <img />
<div>

.round {
  height : 100px;
  width : 100px;
  border-radius : 50%;
}
```

This app I am using it as hybrid application. I tested it in `Samsung Galaxy J7` mobile phone and where I found that image is not displayed.

When I debugged it in chrome inspect and removed border radius image is visible. In other devices in android as well as iOS it is working fine with same code.

Answer (score 0):

Some browser required special properties.

Try below code:

```
.round {
  height : 100px;
  width : 100px;  
  -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
  -moz-border-radius:  50% !important;
  border-radius : 50% !important;
}
```